# $mdDialog.prompt throws exception, but the function works fine with confirm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

For some reason, my prompt dialog stopped working in my yo angular fullstack application.

I googled a solution telling me to update my angular, which i did, but it did not solve the problem.

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(ev, ret, value) {
  var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
  .title('Rediger ' + value)
  .textContent('Indtast en ny værdi for: ' + value)
  .placeholder('getValue()')
  .ariaLabel('Ny ' + value)
  .targetEvent(ev)
  .ok('Accepter')
  .cancel('Annuller');
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
  //setValue(result);
});
};
```

Whenever i call the function, i get an error saying TypeError: $mdDialog.prompt is not a function.

If i change the dialog to a .confirm and remove the placeholder it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
In javascript a variable as function is defined at runtime :

```
//This code throw an error
getValue();
var getValue = function(){};
```

You have to declare your variable function before calling it :

```
//Ok
var getValue = function(){};
getValue();
```

You could also write something like

```
//Ok because code block is parsed before runtime
getValue();
function getValue(){};
```

So here your plunker edited
https://plnkr.co/edit/YqeyaLqW2B6xn4VHcVlQ?p=preview

Comment: :That is why i posted this :/  i can not find the error.

Comment: Your error isn't throw by the partial code you provide. Can you create a plunker / jsfiddle or whatever with your controller / view ?

Comment: I think that's the base of it

Comment: still the same problem, even if try to run just the bacis dialog.prompt i get the error. it's like i've somehow broken the dialog.prompt somewhere

Comment: Have you look at my modified plunker ? It seems to work as expected. your probleme was in the ".placeholder(getValue())" argument, you where calling the variable 'getValue' function before it was created.

Comment: Yes, copied in the code, ive deleted all of it and just copied in the basic prompt i linked in the original question. Right now i've gone back to just using javascripts native prompt function, which seems to work.

Comment: Be care, by using it out of angular scope, you'll have to play with some $scope.$apply and others funky stuff. But at the end, if it works for you, it's cool :)

Answer (score 5):

I realize an answer has already been accepted, but it didn't solve my problem so I wanted to provide an alternate suggestion.

I ran into the exact same situation and it turned out that I was using an old version of Angular Material that hadn't introduced .prompt() yet.  If you check out the [docs for the version I was using](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/) (1.0.5) you'll see in the demo that there is no prompt option for dialog.  But if you look at the [docs for the latest version](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc4/) (1.1.0 as of this writing), the prompt option is there.

Hope this helps anybody who comes across this question like I did.